# ¿Como pasar un dato desde Javascript a Php Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

lo que estoy intentando hacer es una función en javascript que envie un simple dato a un controllador de laravel para después subirlo a la base de datos, el problema que tengo es que hasta el momento no he podido encontrar la forma de enviar ese dato, siempre me sale error 500.

controllador en laravel:

```
 public function crearRegistro(Request $request){

    $registro = new Registro();
    $registro->indicador = $request->indicador;
    $registro->save();

}
```

Función en Javascript:

```
 $scope.calculoIndicador = function(){
  $http.post("/calculoIndicador")
  .then(function(response) {
    });
  $scope.indicador = 5 +5;
   alert('Se ha guardado correctamente');

}
```

La función javascript la estoy utilizando con un botón en la vista.

```
<input class="btn btn-success" style="" ng-click="calculoIndicador()" 
 type="submit" value="Enviar"/>
```

Y también tengo todo listo en la ruta

Comment: ¿cómo está definidal a ruta en Laravel?

Comment: creo que la ruta esta bien: Route::post('/calculoIndicador', 'TecnologiaController@crearRegistro');

Comment: Entonces revisa el inspector de Chrome o el log de Laravel, ahí aparece el motivo del error.

Comment: el error que aparece es este: "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'indicador' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `registros` (`indicador`) values ())"

Comment: dice que el valor no puede ser nulo, es como si no estuviese pasando el valor de la variable.

Comment: Intenta mover esta linea al inicio de la funcion: `$scope.indicador = 5 +5;`

Comment: nada, acabo de intentarlo y sigue sin funcionar, ¿sera posible que el problema este en el controllador?

Comment: Intentalo asi: `$http.post("/calculoIndicador", {indicador: 10})`

Comment: ok así funciona, pero ¿de esa forma podré enviar datos provenientes de otras funciones?, porque yo puse 5+5 en modo de ejemplo, pero en realidad lo que necesito es que ese Indicador se calcule con una función que ya tengo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que no estas pasando el parametro indicador al controlador.  Intentalo asi:

```
$http.post("/calculoIndicador", {indicador: 10})
```

El numero 10 lo puedes reemplazar por cualquier variable que desees.

Comment: Gracias, tu solución me ayudo bastante.